xlsx to pdf using pywin32 unable to save pdf
I am trying to save an excel sheet by opening the file in excel with the pywin32 package. The file will open, however it crashes when trying to save as a pdf. My hunch is it is a printer issue of some kind, but curious to see anyone had any other input. I've tried several other methods of saving as a pdf with the api with no success. I can save no problem manually though.
def excel_to_pdf(date, _id):
    excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = 0
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('xlsx_filepath.xlsx')    
    pdf_file = f"{_id}_{date}.pdf"    
    pdf_filepath = os.path.join(PDF_DIRECTORY, pdf_file)
    
    wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(client.constants.xlTypePDF, pdf_filepath)
    # wb.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, pdf_filepath)
    # wb.ActiveSheet.SaveAs(pdf_filepath, FileFormat=57)

    wb.Close(SaveChanges=False)
    excel.Quit()


Ahhh, I am running a 365 version of Excel, specifically "Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2401 Build 16.0.17231.20236) 64-bit".  SO would there just be a different DLL function I need to call with the API?
